# Cloud SQL database seems to always shutdown even with 'Always On' activation

Tags: java, google-cloud-sql

I am benchmarking Google Cloud SQL. I started with the default "On Demand" activation policy since I work on a test platform with very few hits to save a few $.

It takes about 20-30s to connect for the very first queries (which I think was caused by the database to be started). After that, performance is great.

Now I switched to "Always ON" activation policy. I was expecting to have the exact same response times on the very first requests on my website. BUT: just like the "On Demand" policy, it takes about 30s to reconnect to the database. The time is spent in the connection pool trying to reconnect to the database so I am sure it is Cloud SQL time.

I suspect the "Always ON" policy to do absolutely nothing (except maybe cost more $? I haven't checked yet) and I got the feeling that the database continues to be shutdown. Maybe it changes the timeout policy slightly?

I found out this thread :
[First connect from Prestashop to Google Cloud SQL always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457437/first-connect-from-prestashop-to-google-cloud-sql-always-fails)

So apparently there are still timeouts, but we can change it depending on the billing plan?
This is very unclear to me.

So here are my questions:

- What is the timeout of a SQL instance for "Always ON" policy with "Per Use" billing?
- What is the timeout of a SQL instance for "Always ON" policy with "Package" billing?
- Is there a way I can manually set my own timeouts? After all, I am the one who pays... If I want my instance to keep running, that is my problem.

**EDIT**

I am sure it is a connection problem because I previously had a 3 seconds timeout on web requests. With this timeout set, all my requests threw the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, general error
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2052)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:582)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:439)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:360)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:118)
        ... 31 more
```

Comment: Please contact us at `cloudsql@google.com` with the name of your instance and the timestamps when you noticed the slow queries. An 'Always On' instance should always be up. Note that fetching data that is not in the InnoDB buffer pool will be more expensive regardless of the activation policy. Also note that a slow connect is an indication of the fact that the instance was not up. A slow query does not.

Comment: Your address `cloudsql@google.com` seems invalid (the email failed). Look at my edit. My instance is `sunny-shadow-658: master-1`

Comment: It's `cloud-sql@google.com`. Sorry for the typo. :-)

Comment: Did you receive any answer from cloud-sql@google.com?

Comment: Yes, I added an answer so that anyone interested can learn about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Cloud SQL support, the problem apparently came from my GCE server "forgetting" tcp connections after 10 minutes. Since it was a test server, the connections to the Cloud SQL instance from there were long-lived unused connection.

So to workaround this, I used the tcp keepalive, as advised by Google:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 60 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time'
```

Information about this configuration could be found here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/gce-access (section 6).

Don't forget to restart any application that makes connection to the Cloud SQL instance after setting this setting.